# Problems creating symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am new to Symfony and tried to follow the installation guide (https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) in the docs. However, I always get this error after running "composer install"

Commands I used:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.2.*" basic
```

cd basic

composer install

```
In CurlDownloader.php line 623:

  The "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 )
```

Anyone also faced this problem?

Tried to change symfony/flex version to ^1.0 in composer.json

Comment: Which guide are you trying to follow? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json loads fine for me, shouldn't be a 404

Comment: @mpen https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

Comment: There are various ways described in that doc, so just pointing to it is not enough description of what you did before getting a problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have just updated my question

Comment: Cannot reproduce this! Just ran it fine, including the unnecessary `composer install` The `composer install` is not required. That is what you do when you download a written project from git and want to make sure the composer provisioned code is all downloaded (the stuff thats managed by composer and not GIT)

Comment: regarding: _"Anyone also faced this problem?"_ -> please use the search to find out. Those who did have created Q&A material already, this is how the site works, compare with the [help]. And welcome again.

Comment: What does `symfony check:requirements` show?  If I had to guess your php and/or composer versions are out of date.  `php --version` and `composer --version` should provide more details.  In particular your composer version should be at least 2.4.4.

Comment: @Cerad Composer version 2.4.4,  Your system is ready to run Symfony projects

Comment: Then maybe a firwall issue of some kind.  Especially if you are running under Windows or maybe some kind of docker setup.  What happens if you run `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json` directly from the command line?  If it fails then try curling some other url to see if curl itself is being blocked.

Comment: You could also try `dig raw.githubusercontent.com` or `nslookup raw.githubusercontent.com` depending on your os. Maybe your DNS is giving you the wrong address for raw.githubusercontent.com. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which version of Flex did you install?

Comment: @hous my ip is actually from Slovakia now

Comment: @Cerad curling works fine... I can also wget the file... I am so stuck with this

Answer (score 3):

After running "composer dignose" I found a misconfiguration in github token. Then I ran "composer config --global --unset github-oauth.github.com" and the problem was solved